# "If" syntax for post-build macros in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event, post-build

I'm trying to to add a post-build macro that would conditionally copy some files after the build if the configuration is not "Debug". I'm trying the following:

```
if ('$(ConfigurationName)' <> 'Debug')
    copy /y $(ProjectDir)memcached.$(ConfigurationName).config   
            $(ProjectDir)memcached.config
```

And I get error 255. 
What should be the right syntax for the 'if' statement?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just figured out:

```
if not $(ConfigurationName) == Debug  
   copy /y $(ProjectDir)memcached.$(ConfigurationName).config 
           $(ProjectDir)memcached.config
```

Comment: Thanks. Was driving me nuts!  Tried <>, != !($(x)==x).  you would think != would be it since they use ==.